# how to determine current localization and add marker to GoogleMapsApi in android

Tags: java, android, maps

I can't resolve this problem. I trying to create Fragment with a map and I have this done. When I add static Long,  Lat value the map show this o a map, But when I trying to make it automatic with getting localization in runnable the application just open the map and don't show specific LongLand values.

How to do this?

For getting long and late I'm using LocalizationManager, of course, I add permissions in manifest and also check runtime

```
public class LocalizationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


private GoogleMap map;
MapView mapView;
View mview;
private double latitude, longtitude;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;


public LocalizationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_localization, container, false);
    handler = new Handler();
    getLocation();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 13);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 11);
    }
    return mview;
}

@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void buttonStart() {
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = (MapView) mview.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longtitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    map = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLocation();
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude)).title("Statue").snippet("Something"));
            CameraPosition liberty = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude)).zoom(15).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(liberty));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add markers form the main thread.add this to your runnable.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude)).title("Statue").snippet("Something"));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem come from synchronize data. If you got location after add marker, it is meaningless, you get no location, and you have no marker on map, try to move action add marker into onLocationChanged

Comment: Iam trying, but then he generate a map without any marker

Comment: this method: requestLocationUpdates some time can not get location, im tried it 3 years ago. Please debug at this point and make sure that you get location. One more problem, you should put requestLocationUpdates in OnRequestPermissionResult to make sure that you have permission to get location